# jQuery - show() does not animation but show(, with a function does? y? How to disable

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
function CommentReplyOpen(id) {
    $('#commentReply_' + id).show(function() {
        $('#commentReply_' + id).find('.comment_content').focus();
    });
}
```

Problem here is that when it runs jQuery is doig some strange easing animation. but if you do just .show() there is no animation... How can I use the above, since I want a call back, but not have an animation, just go from display:none to display

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument for the `$.show()` method is for the duration — simply provide a very short duration, and then your callback method.

```
$("#foo").show( 1, function(){
  $(".bar", this).focus();
});
```

Alternatively, you could simply chain your logic:

```
$("#foo").show().children(".bar").focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `show` must always be the duration: http://api.jquery.com/show/

You can use `0` to have it happen instantly.

```
$('#commentReply_' + id).show(0, function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if this would work-- could you just set the css to change from "display: none" or "visibility: hidden" to whatever value you want? http://api.jquery.com/css/